# How to transfer the database contents (products) from version 1.3.1 to version 1.9.1?

Tags: database, ce-1.9.1.0, magento-1.3

I am not so good at this - I have an old Magento (1.3.1) store with about 1300 products. Now - I decided to make a fresh install of the newest (1.9.1) version. I have that running on an IP address before I manage to put all of my products in and then change the domain DNS to forward the traffic to the new store running the new Magento version. The problem is - I have been putting the products in by hand and *it takes a very very long time* (they all have different sizes, colors and so on). Is there a safe way to automatically transfer all the products from a 1.3.1 database to a 1.9.1 database? I mean - it's kind of hard for me to imagine how this would work if for example the categories I set up might not even have the exact same name...Thanks for any suggestions! :-* Allysin

Comment: Why didn't you upgrade the database?

Answer (score 1):

Are all your attributes the same? You could use import/export to export all products from your old store and then import to your new. Its under system import/export in admin. If your categories are different you could manually tweak the data in the CSV and then bulk import the updated data.

Comment: Hi - I clicked on Import/Export - Export All Products and it's going through the process right now. You say there will be a CSV file which I would then IMPORT into the 1.9.1 database? Does this include the product photos? Because if it does - it would be HUGE (I have 1300 products). Is there any way to test if it works first before I put it into the database where I already entered the 300 products by hand...?

Comment: No it doesn't export the images, it exports the path to the image. So what you would need to do is upload your existing media to the media/import folder on your new site. see http://www.integer-net.com/2012/04/04/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/. You could try it with a small sample of products first if you are worried about breaking things.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely run your backup of your 1.3 database against the new version of Magento and it will upgrade the database to work with version 1.9. The steps are as follows:

1) Backup your old site (version 1.3) 
2) Restore the backup to a NEW database. Remember if you have to re-do this step it must be a new CLEAN database. You can simply restore to the same database without dropping and recreating it first.
3) Point your new version of Magento to the old database. If you use Magerun you can do the process directly from the command line

After the process is complete you will have all your products, categories, customers (EVERYTHING!!) in the new version of Magento without having to do any import or export.